# Jupyter - importing class from an imported notebook

Tags: python, class, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to import a class from another notebook and following [this tutorial](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html) I am doing something wrong which i don't get.

I have

```
#(Building.ipynb)

class Class ():
    def __init__ ():     
        "this is my class"
        print ("I am a new class instance")
```

and all the code exactly as in the tutorial.

When I try:

```
sys.meta_path.append(NotebookFinder())
import Building
a = Class()
#(or)
a = Building.Class()
```

I get:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-ecc443c1045a> in <module>()
      1 sys.meta_path.append(NotebookFinder())
      2 import Building
----> 3 a = Class()
      4 #(or)
      5 a = Building.Class()

NameError: name 'Class' is not defined
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply delete the line `a = Class()` since the correct way to call your `Class` constructor is `Building.Class()`, which you had, but your code fails before it can run the correct code.

Also - you'll need to change `def __init__():` to `def __init__(self):` since `__init__` needs a reference to itself.

Comment: Yes. I have by now learned to to write code directly in Python and (very simply) import it into the notebook. Thanks